# ORA-00904: "pass": invalid identifier

Tags: java, netbeans, sqlplus

I have a project named 'Online Recruitment System'. There is problem in database connectivity.

First i made table 'registration' and 'clogindetails' without using quotes in sqlplus. 
Then all data used to save properly, but on login I was getting following error:

`java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: PASSWORD: invalid identifier`

After this I read stackoverflow multiple examples. And I added "double quotes" to the table items  in database and kept them in lowercase.

Now the data is not even getting saved. I tried to look in 'object browser' in 'data' tab and there was following error:

```
failed to parse SQL query:
ORA-00904: "pass": invalid identifier
```

As far I know the project is made all right. Only there is problem in making tables.

Here is code from one of the page which use table 'clogindetails':

```
   String usrname=getClogid();
   String pass=getCpassword();

   if(usrname!=null && pass!=null && usrname.length()>0 && pass.length()>0)
   {
      ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from clogindetails where logid=? and password=?");
      ps.setString(1,usrname);
      ps.setString(2,pass);
      rs=ps.executeQuery();
      HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
      if(!rs.next())
      {
         errors.add("invalid", new ActionMessage("errors.invalidusername"));
      }
   }

   rs.close();
   ps.close();
   con.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}

if(getClogid()==null || getClogid().length()<1)
{
   errors.add("logid", new ActionMessage("errors.logid.required"));
}

if(getCpassword()==null || getCpassword().length()<1)
{
   errors.add("password", new ActionMessage("errors.password.required"));
}
return errors;
```

the schema of clogindetails is

```
CREATE TABLE "CLOGINDETAILS"(
   "ADMITID" NUMBER(15,0),
   "NAME" VARCHAR2(25),
   "LOGID" VARCHAR2(10),
   "PASS" VARCHAR2(20)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**ORA-00904** is common when **invalid alias in a select statement is referred**.

To overcome this error, you need enter a **valid column name**.

To avoid **ORA-00904**, column names cannot be a **reserved word**, and must contain these four criteria to be valid:

- begin with a letter
- be less than or equal to thirty characters
- consist only of alphanumeric and the special characters ($_#); other characters need double quotation marks around them

For more info you can refer this link.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00904_string_invalid_identifier.htm

Answer (score 0):

By looking at user exception error i could say that such type of exceptions are occurred when we are using different column names. 
for ex:
i have created table in database i.e
create table tb_login(username varchar(10), password varchar(10));

and my java code is

ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from tb_login where username=? and pass=?");
                                                                  //error bcz pass
This code will produce same exception  bcz in my database second column name is password not pass.
so check your database schema and java code. or else share your database schema.

Comment: create table clogindetails("admitid" varchar2(100), "name" varchar2(100), "logid" varchar2(100), "pass" varchar2(100));

Comment: I made changes to the database, but now there is new error and data is not saving - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "LOGID": invalid identifier

Comment: what changes you made ?? invalid identifier means same error check database column name and java code name..

Comment: I changed word pass to password in database. And I removed double quotes. Now data is saving properly. But on login I am getting a new error, java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

Comment: CREATE TABLE CLOGINDETAILS( ADMITID VARCHAR2(100), 
 NAME VARCHAR2(100), 
 LOGID VARCHAR2(100), 
 PASSWORD VARCHAR2(100)
   );

Comment: CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION 
   ( ADMITID VARCHAR2(100), 
 NAME VARCHAR2(100), 
 LOGID VARCHAR2(100), 
 PASSWORD VARCHAR2(100), 
 DOB VARCHAR2(100), 
 SEX VARCHAR2(100), 
 TENTH VARCHAR2(100), 
 TENTHYEAR VARCHAR2(100), 
 TWELTH VARCHAR2(100), 
 TWELTHYEAR VARCHAR2(100), 
 QUALI VARCHAR2(100), 
 BRANCH VARCHAR2(100), 
 INSTITUTE VARCHAR2(100), 
 PERCENT VARCHAR2(100), 
 PASSING VARCHAR2(100), 
 EXP VARCHAR2(100), 
 ANYGAP VARCHAR2(100), 
 COURSE VARCHAR2(100), 
 EMAIL VARCHAR2(100), 
 MOB VARCHAR2(100), 
 RESUMENAME VARCHAR2(100), 
 CPHOTO VARCHAR2(100));

Comment: ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from clogindetails where logid=? and password=?");
        ps.setString(1, usrname);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
        if(rs.next())

Comment: {
            String cname=rs.getString("name");
            String clogid=rs.getString("logid");
            int admit=rs.getInt("admitid");
            String admitid=String.valueOf(admit);
            
            session.setAttribute("cname",cname);
            session.setAttribute("clogid",clogid);
            session.setAttribute("admitid",admitid);
            
             
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            con.close();
            
            result="Success";
        }
        else

Comment: { 

            session.setAttribute("cname","");
            session.setAttribute("clogid","");
            session.setAttribute("admitid","");
            con.close();
            result="Failure";
        }
       
    return mapping.findForward(result);
    }
}

Comment: There are multiple programs in project, I had sent you prepareStatement query from one of the program.

Comment: This prepareStatement is fine according to db so some other prepareStatement producing error so u need to share all preparestatement form your error pgm then only i can help..or else share your program...

Comment: ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from clogindetails where logid=? and password=?");
        ps.setString(1, usrname);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
        if(rs.next())
        {

Comment: ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from clogindetails where logid=? and password=?");
        ps.setString(1,usrname);
        ps.setString(2,pass);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
        
        if(!rs.next())
        {

Comment: ps1=con.prepareStatement("update clogindetails set name=?,password=? where admitid=?");
            ps1.setString(1,name);
            ps1.setString(2,pass);
            ps1.setInt(3,admitid);
            ps1.executeUpdate();

Comment: PreparedStatement ps4=con.prepareStatement("insert into clogindetails values(?,?,?,?)");
            ps4.setInt(1,admitid);
            ps4.setString(2,name);
            ps4.setString(3,logid);
            ps4.setString(4,pass);
            ps4.executeUpdate();

Comment: PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from clogindetails where admitid=? and name=?");
        ps.setInt(1,admitid);
        ps.setString(2,name);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {

Comment: ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from clogindetails where admitid=? and name=?");
        ps.setInt(1,aid);
        ps.setString(2,name);
        
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        
        
        if(!rs.next())
        {

Comment: String cname=rs.getString("name");                                      String clogid=rs.getString("logid"); int admit=rs.getInt("admitid");        check this u are accessing admitid value as int but in your db this value is String so use String admit=rs.getString("admitid")..

Comment: ps3=con.prepareStatement("insert into registration values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps3.setInt(1,admitid);
            ps3.setString(2,name);
            ps3.setString(3,logid);
            ps3.setString(4,pass);
            ps3.setString(5,dob);

Comment: I made these changes in table CREATE TABLE  "REGISTRATION" 
   ( "ADMITID" NUMBER(15,0), 
 "NAME" VARCHAR2(25), 
 "LOGID" VARCHAR2(10), 
 "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(20), 
 "DOB" VARCHAR2(20), 
 "SEX" VARCHAR2(20), 
 "TENTH" NUMBER(10,0), 
 "TENTHYEAR" NUMBER(10,0), 
 "TWELTH" NUMBER(10,0), 
 "TWELTHYEAR" NUMBER(10,0), 
 "QUALI" VARCHAR2(10), 
 "BRANCH" VARCHAR2(10), 
 "INSTITUTE" VARCHAR2(30), 
 "PERCENT" NUMBER(10,0), 
 "PASSING" NUMBER(10,0), 
 "EXP" NUMBER(10,0), 
 "

Comment: And I again get this error - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

Comment: I changed word password to pass in database and I again get same earlier error message - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "PASSWORD": invalid identifier

Comment: see u are getting password invalid identifier it means somewhere you are using password identifier. and don't use double quotes to create db. plz share me whole pgm and that pgm exceptions then only i can help you..or else send ur project jar file my id omjay.jadhav@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

k now try this

ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from clogindetails where logid=? and pass=?");

rest of the code keep as it is..

Comment: I changed, now the error is : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "PASS": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this one:

Change your query

from: `select * from clogindetails where logid=? and password=?`

to: `select * from clogindetails where logid='?' and password='?'`

Point is that when you make queries, you should spot your identifiers with ' ', otherwise it seems like you are comparing some unknown table column's data (variables) with data from existing columns.

ex: `select e.full_name from e.employees where e.full_name like '&Medet&'` 
otherwise you'll get an error.

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your column name not as same as you are writing in your query . and avoid to give column names which are Keyword of oracle ,  Group this cant be your column name or table name.